# Xdebug not stops at breakpoint in Eclipse Kepler

Tags: php, eclipse, xampp, xdebug

I asked this question before but not in detail enough.

My problem is, I use Eclipse Kepler with the PDT Plugin from this site:
Kepler - http://download.eclipse.org/releases/kepler

And I use XAMPP 1.8.3.

The problem is, my XDebug not stopping at breakpoints.

My settings are as follow:

**php.ini**

```
[XDebug]
zend_extension = "C:\dev\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug.dll"
;xdebug.profiler_append = 0
;xdebug.profiler_enable = 1
;xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = 0
;xdebug.profiler_output_dir = "C:\development\xampp\tmp"
;xdebug.profiler_output_name = "cachegrind.out.%t-%s"
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_handler = "dbgp"
xdebug.remote_host = "127.0.0.1"
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_cookie_expire_time = 25920000
;xdebug.trace_output_dir = "C:\development\xampp\tmp"
```

In Eclipse I have:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

If I check "Break at first line" it stops. But if I call a page, like index.php it do not stop although I set breakpoints in this file.

Is it possible to use Xdebug in Eclipse Kepler?

**EDIT**
I set the xdebug.remote_log property into php.ini.
By start debugging idekey is set correctly in the logs:

```
idekey="ECLIPSE_DBGP"
```

Now, if I call a page in my webapp like feedback.php the idekey is suddenly:

```
idekey="netbeans-xdebug"
```

I think this could be the problem. But how can I change the Ide key eclipse send?

**EDIT 2**

I realized too, that xdebug only not works in external browser. In eclipse internal browser I am able to debug.

Answer (score 0):

Oh man :-)
I cannot believe what my mistake was.
I installed the firefox extension "the easiest xdebug" and it has value "netbeans-xdebug" in the configs.
Simply deactivated the extension and now it works. :-)